# Data binding dynamic data

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a set of 'dynamic data' that I need to bind to the GridControl. Up until now, I have been using the standard DataTable class that's part of the System.Data namespace. This has worked fine, but I've been told I cannot use this as it's too heavy for serialization across the network between client & server.

So I thought I could easy replicate a 'cut-down' version of the DataTable class by simply having a type of `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` whereby the List represents the collection of rows, and each Dictionary represents one row with the column names and values as a KeyValuePair type. I could set up the Grid to have the column DataField properties to match those of the keys in the Dictionary (just like I was doing for the DataTable's column names.

However after doing

```
gridControl.DataSource = table;
gridControl.RefreshDataSource();
```

The grid has no data...

I think I need to implement `IEnumerator` - any help on this would be much appreciated!

Example calling code looks like this:

```
var table = new List<Dictionary<string,object>>();

var row = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {"Field1", "Data1"},
    {"Field2", "Data2"},
    {"Field3", "Data3"}
};

table.Add(row);

gridControl1.DataSource = table;
gridControl1.RefreshDataSource();
```

Comment: GridControl? Do you mean DataGridView?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of System.ComponentModel. This dark corner of .NET is very powerful, but very complex.

A word of caution; unless you have a lot of time for this - you may do well to simply serialize it in whatever mechanism you are happy with, but rehydrate it back into a `DataTable` at each end... what follows is not for the faint-hearted ;-p

Firstly - data binding (for tables) works against *lists* (`IList`/`IListSource`) - so `List<T>` should be fine (edited: I misread something). But it isn't going to understand that your dictionary is actually columns...

To get a type to pretend to have columns you need to use custom `PropertyDescriptor` implementations. There are several ways to do this, depending on whether the column definitions are always the same (but determined at runtime, i.e. perhaps from config), or whether it changes per usage (like how each `DataTable` instance can have different columns).

For "per instance" customisation, you need to look at `ITypedList` - this beast (implemented in *addition* to `IList`) has the fun task of presenting properties for tabular data... but it isn't alone:

For "per type" customisation, you can look at `TypeDescriptionProvider` - this can suggest dynamic properties for a class...

...or you can implement `ICustomTypeDescriptor` - but this is only used (for lists) in **very** occasional circumstances (an object indexer (`public object this[int index] {get;}`") and at least one row in the list at the point of binding). (this interface is much more useful when binding discrete objects - i.e. not lists).

Implementing `ITypedList`, and providing a `PropertyDescriptor` model is hard work... hence it is only done very occasionally. I'm fairly familiar with it, but I wouldn't do it just for laughs...

---

Here's a **very, very simplified** implementation (all columns are strings; no notifications (via descriptor), no validation (`IDataErrorInfo`), no conversions (`TypeConverter`), no additional list support (`IBindingList`/`IBindingListView`), no abstraction (`IListSource`), no other other metadata/attributes, etc):

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        PropertyBagList list = new PropertyBagList();
        list.Columns.Add("Foo");
        list.Columns.Add("Bar");
        list.Add("abc", "def");
        list.Add("ghi", "jkl");
        list.Add("mno", "pqr");

        Application.Run(new Form {
            Controls = {
                new DataGridView {
                    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                    DataSource = list
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
class PropertyBagList : List<PropertyBag>, ITypedList
{
    public PropertyBag Add(params string[] args)
    {
        if (args == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("args");
        if (args.Length != Columns.Count) throw new ArgumentException("args");
        PropertyBag bag = new PropertyBag();
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            bag[Columns[i]] = args[i];
        }
        Add(bag);
        return bag;
    }
    public PropertyBagList() { Columns = new List<string>(); }
    public List<string> Columns { get; private set; }

    PropertyDescriptorCollection ITypedList.GetItemProperties(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
    {
        if(listAccessors == null || listAccessors.Length == 0)
        {
            PropertyDescriptor[] props = new PropertyDescriptor[Columns.Count];
            for(int i = 0 ; i < props.Length ; i++)
            {
                props[i] = new PropertyBagPropertyDescriptor(Columns[i]);
            }
            return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(props, true);            
        }
        throw new NotImplementedException("Relations not implemented");
    }

    string ITypedList.GetListName(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
    {
        return "Foo";
    }
}
class PropertyBagPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
{
    public PropertyBagPropertyDescriptor(string name) : base(name, null) { }
    public override object GetValue(object component)
    {
        return ((PropertyBag)component)[Name];
    }
    public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
    {
        ((PropertyBag)component)[Name] = (string)value;
    }
    public override void ResetValue(object component)
    {
        ((PropertyBag)component)[Name] = null;
    }
    public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
    {
        return ((PropertyBag)component)[Name] != null;
    }
    public override Type PropertyType
    {
        get { return typeof(string); }
    }
    public override bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
    public override Type ComponentType
    {
        get { return typeof(PropertyBag); }
    }
}
class PropertyBag
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> values
        = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public string this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            string value;
            values.TryGetValue(key, out value);
            return value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null) values.Remove(key);
            else values[key] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ouch... My eyes are bleeding. I go back to datasets and dynamic columns collections :D

Comment: @MarcGravell How would you solve the problem of implementing many different sql types in your above example? Without using the object..?

Comment: @John can you be more specific? In particular, when did we start talking about SQL types? Happy to help, but need context.

Comment: @MarcGravell Ah sorry it was late and I was tired. I meant, how can the PropertyBag be rewritten to store and return different types? Is it possible to do it without object type?

Comment: @John right; you can do much more sophisticated things with `PropertyBag` - you just need the `PropertyDescriptor`'s `PropertyType` to return the right thing. However, as I mentioned - this is essentially duplicating a lot of work making it gradually closer to what `DataTable` does. I don't like `DataTable`, but it is a reasonable fit when handling flexible schema.