# C# run time class creation

Tags: c#, reflection, propertygrid

I'm new to C# and I heard that is possible to create classes at run time. Is this true? If it's true can you give me a simple example on how to do it? I want to create a class from a configuration file at run time to use it as SelectedObject in PropertyGrid control.

Thanks for help!

Comment: You want to create a new Class at runtime? or a new instance of a class type known at runtime?

Comment: I want a new class, with new members and new methods. All of them added at run time. I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: Do you really want a new class? Or do you just want to display arbitrary data in a property grid? If so, there are easier ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually want to do is display arbitrary data in a PropertyGrid. You don't need to create a new class for this. You can just use a custom type descriptor.

Check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/bending_property.aspx) out.

Comment: Actually, you don't even need a full descriptor; a converter by itself can do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can, with TypeBuilder - but this is **not** trivial stuff; you are essentially writing low-level things like IL at runtime. I do this occasionally, but I'm a bit crazy. The two may be related.

For what you want (PropertyGrid) a simpler option is to provide runtime properties via PropertyDescriptor; I have several such "property bag" examples here on stackoverflow. Here's one such example: [.Net Property Grid. Is there a way to let the Grid manipulate object in different way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931644/net-property-grid-is-there-a-way-to-let-the-grid-manipulate-object-in-different/931651#931651)

But even that is work compared to the simplest option: use a DataTable; add the columns you want and a single row, and pass the row's twin from the table's DefaultView to the PropertyGrid.

Comment: Thanks @Cody - fat fingers this am

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the [TypeBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.aspx) class. The linked MSDN documentation has an example.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is [dynamic source code generation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/650ax5cx.aspx) which allows you to create classes etc at runtime. Link includes samples.