# WPF DataGrid AutoColumn generation via ICustomTypeDescriptor

Tags: c#, wpf, icustomtypedescriptor

In a test project I've managed to AutoGenerate WPF DataGrid columns in the following scenario, where the data is stored in a Dictionary and binding is performed via PropertyDescriptors:

```
public class People:List<Person>{
     ...
}
public class Person:Dictionary<string,string>,INotifyPropertyChanged,ICustomTypeDescriptor
{

}
```

The problem I'm having is in my real life project I'm using MVVM so it's *People*ViewModel which inherits ViewModelBase and hence can't inherit List<Person>.  I've tried implementing IList<Person> instead with an internal List<Person> and explicitly setting the DataContext to an IList<Person> reference but that didn't work.

I've seen a similar post on binding a win forms DataGridView [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468840/datagridview-not-showing-properites-of-objects-which-implement-icustomtypedescrip), so I'm wondering if the same sort of logic applies in WPF and primarily, what exactly causes the ICustomTypeDescriptor implementation to be picked up when inheriting List<T> that is missing when you simply implement IList<T> instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `DataGrid` uses the `CollectionView` for your collection to generate the properties.  More specifically, it casts the `CollectionView` to `IItemProperties`, which the default `CollectionView` doesn't implement.  If you don't implement `IList` (NOT the generic one), then the default `CollectionView` will be used.

So, implementing the non-generic `IList` interface should solve this (`List<T>` implements both, which is why it works if you derive from `List<Person>`).

Comment: Fantastic, that works with an IList implementation as you suggested, many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Since it's not mentioned already, I had a related problem where the columns in the `DataGrid` were not being auto-generated when there were no rows; it turns out that the `DataGrid` wasn't looking at my `IItemProperties` implementation at all (I don't know why), but was using purely the `ICustomTypeDescriptor` implementation on each individual row object to generate the columns, which works too but results in there being no columns when there are no rows.

The solution was to implement `ITypedList` (I left the `IItemProperties` implementation too just in case) on the collection type. Now I get columns properly generated for me in whether or not there are rows.