# How does datagridview enumerate columns in a datatable?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

simpler question, How do I make my own?

```
public class MyClass {//this works with DataGridView
    public int MyField1 { get; set; }
    public int MyField2 { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass {//How do I make this one work instead?
    IDictinary<string, int> MyFields { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Derive you class from GridView and override whatever the method you want to, in your case binding.

Comment: So you want to enumerate all fields in your class?

Comment: You could make it work, but why? Any reason you can't use compile time properties?

Comment: Hmmm..., I want to stick to existing code if possible, (Have enough spaghetti in that area), waiting for some code from .net dark internal stuff

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes, I'll have to make over 300 properties that way, the user doesn't need to see all the columns at the same time And I really don't want to write the name of each column a dozen times.

Comment: It is not easy as you may expect. But possible with [ICustomTypeDesciptor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1469722/2530848)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thank you, that's exactly what I want. You should write it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I closed your question as duplicate of the aforementioned question in comments. That should help you. If you disagree, comment it here.

Comment: no, it's completely fine, thanks again.