# Trying to use DataGridView together with ICustomTypeDescriptor

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, icustomtypedescriptor

I'm trying to use the **DataGridView** to display a list of objects.
In the class that I want to present properties for I have some C# properties and I also want to create properties dynamically for some reasons.

Here I have an example, that works fine for the C# property (FeatureId) but the dynamically created property (Name) returns the value of the first instance for all the instances. **Why?**

First a class that implements the ICustomPropertyDescriptor interface

```
public abstract class PropertyPresentationSubBase : ICustomTypeDescriptor
{
public String GetClassName()
{
  return TypeDescriptor.GetClassName(this, true);
}

public AttributeCollection GetAttributes()
{
  return TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(this, true);
}

public String GetComponentName()
{
  return TypeDescriptor.GetComponentName(this, true);
}

public TypeConverter GetConverter()
{
  return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(this, true);
}

public EventDescriptor GetDefaultEvent()
{
  return TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultEvent(this, true);
}

public PropertyDescriptor GetDefaultProperty()
{
  return TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultProperty(this, true);
}

public object GetEditor(Type editorBaseType)
{
  return TypeDescriptor.GetEditor(this, editorBaseType, true);
}

public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents(Attribute[] attributes)
{
  return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(this, attributes, true);
}

public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents()
{
  return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(this, true);
}


public virtual PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
{
  PropertyDescriptorCollection rtn = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this);

  //rtn = FilterReadonly(rtn, attributes);

  return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(rtn.Cast<PropertyDescriptor>().ToArray());


}

public virtual PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
{

  return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this, true);

}


public object GetPropertyOwner(PropertyDescriptor pd)
{
  return this;
}

[Browsable(false)]
public PropertyPresentationSubBase Parent
{
  get
  {
    return m_Parent;
  }
  set
  {
    m_Parent = value;
  }
}

PropertyPresentationSubBase m_Parent = null;

[Browsable(false)]
public Type ValueType
{
  get
  {
    return valueType;
  }
  set
  {
    valueType = value;
  }
}

private Type valueType = null;

[Browsable(false)]
public string Name
{
  get
  {
    return sName;
  }
  set
  {
    sName = value;
  }
}



public abstract object GetValue();

private string sName = string.Empty;

public abstract void Change(object value);


  }
}
```

I also have a class that inherit from PropertyDescriptor

```
public class MyCustomPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
{
PropertyPresentationSubBase m_Property;

public MyCustomPropertyDescriptor(PropertyPresentationSubBase myProperty, Attribute[] attrs, int propertyNo)
  : base(myProperty.Name + propertyNo, attrs)
{
  m_Property = myProperty;
}

#region PropertyDescriptor specific

public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
{
  return false;
}

public override string Name
{
  get
  {
    return "MyName";
  }
}

public override Type ComponentType
{
  get
  {
    return null;
  }
}

public override object GetValue(object component)
{
  return m_Property.GetValue();
}


public override string Description
{
  get
  {
    return "Description";
  }
}



public object Value
{
  get
  {
    return m_Property;
  }
}


public override string Category
{
  get
  {
    return "Category";
  }
}

public override string DisplayName
{
  get
  {
    return m_Property.Name;
  }

}


public override bool IsReadOnly
{
  get
  {
    return false;
  }
}


public override void ResetValue(object component)
{
  //Have to implement
}

public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
{
  return false;
}




public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
{
  m_Property.Change(value);
}

public override Type PropertyType
{

  get
  {
    if ((m_Property != null) &&  (m_Property.ValueType != null))
    {
      return m_Property.ValueType;
    }
    else
    {
      return System.Type.Missing.GetType();

    }
  }
}

#endregion
```

}

A small class that holds the data:

```
public class QuadriFeatureItem
{
public QuadriFeatureItem(int featureId, string name)
{
  m_featureId = featureId;
  m_name = name;

}
public int m_featureId;

public string m_name;
}
```

My class that is sent to the grid (containing both the FeatureId property and the dynamically created property)

```
class FeaturePropertyPresentation : PropertyPresentationSubBase
{

public int FeatureId
{
  get
  {
    return m_feature.m_featureId;

  }
  set { m_feature.m_featureId = value; }
}

public FeaturePropertyPresentation(QuadriFeatureItem item)
{
  m_feature = item;
}

private QuadriFeatureItem m_feature;

public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
{
  PropertyDescriptorCollection rtn = base.GetProperties(attributes);

  CreateNameAttribute(ref rtn, attributes);

  return rtn;

}

private void CreateNameAttribute(ref PropertyDescriptorCollection pdc, Attribute[] attributes)
{

  NameProperty namePres = null;
  namePres = new NameProperty(m_feature, this);

  pdc.Add(new MyCustomPropertyDescriptor(namePres, attributes, pdc.Count));

}

public override void Change(object value)
{
  throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public override object GetValue()
{
  return this;
}
```

}

A class that implements the nameproperty:

```
class NameProperty : PropertyPresentationSubBase
{

public NameProperty(QuadriFeatureItem feature, FeaturePropertyPresentation parent)
  : base()
 {
   m_quadriFeatureItem = feature;
   Parent = parent;
   ValueType = typeof(string);

 }

private QuadriFeatureItem m_quadriFeatureItem;

public override void Change(object value)
{
  m_quadriFeatureItem.m_name = (string)value;
}

public override object GetValue()
{

  return m_quadriFeatureItem.m_name;

}  

}
```

And my formcode:

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  ShowGrid();
}

private void ShowGrid()
{

  QuadriFeatureItem no1 = new QuadriFeatureItem(1, "Nummer1");
  QuadriFeatureItem no2 = new QuadriFeatureItem(2, "Nummer2");
  QuadriFeatureItem no3 = new QuadriFeatureItem(3, "Nummer3");

  BindingSource source = new BindingSource();

  FeaturePropertyPresentation no1Pres = new FeaturePropertyPresentation(no1);
  FeaturePropertyPresentation no2Pres = new FeaturePropertyPresentation(no2);
  FeaturePropertyPresentation no3Pres = new FeaturePropertyPresentation(no3);

  source.Add(no1Pres);
  source.Add(no2Pres);
  source.Add(no3Pres);

  dataGridView1.DataSource = source;

  Show();      
}
```

But the grid shows "Nummer1" for all rows. Why? I use this presentation classes in a propertygrid and it works fine. I also use this MyCustomPropertyDescriptor in a propertygrid.

My wish is now to be able to reuse this presentationclasses and MyCustomPropertyDescriptor in a datagridview. Is it possible with any modification in the MyCustomPropertyDescriptor or PropertyPresentationSubBase?

Comment: Maybe its related to the implementation of `ICustomTypeDescriptor`,  so its better to post your implementation.

Comment: It definitely is possible, but you need to show your implementation.

Comment: What about showing the code of `MyCustomPropertyDescriptor`? See, if you want help, you need to provide us with enough information. All I can say so far is that the problem is in your code.

Comment: I see the problem, but in order to suggest you a solution, I also need the code for your `FeatureNamePresentation` class. Also noticed that your custom property descriptor seems to have a member `m_Property` of type `PropertyPresentationSubBase` but is using properties/methods not shown in the abstract class above. When asking a question, as a  minimum you should provide a code that is **compilable** and can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Replaced the whole content with a small example now that has the problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your custom property descriptor is bound to a concrete instance. Which works when you use **single item data binding** (like `TextBox` to your object property or selecting your object in a `PropertyGrid` control). However, when you use a control that requires **list data binding** (like `DataGridView`, `ListView`, `ListBox`, `ComboBox` list etc.) this technique doesn't work. In order to auto populate the columns, `DataGridView` needs a set of properties that are **common** to all items. In order to do that, it tries several ways to obtain that information (a good explanation can be found here [DataGridView not showing properites of objects which implement ICustomTypeDescriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468840/datagridview-not-showing-properites-of-objects-which-implement-icustomtypedescri?rq=1)), and one of them is to take the first item of the list and ask for properties (hence your debugging experience). Anyway, in order to make this work in a list binding scenarios, your property descriptor needs to be implemented differently.

Notice the signature of the `PropertyDescriptor`s `GetValue/SetValue` methods. Both they have an argument `object component`. This is the object instance you need to return or set the value. You can think of property descriptor being an inverse of what we usually use in a programming language. So instead of

```
var val = obj.Property;
obj.Property = val;
```

we have

```
var val = propertyDescriptor.GetValue(obj);
propertyDescriptor.SetValue(obj, val);
```

In other words, you should not "embed" your object instance inside the property descriptor, but use the passed argument.

Here is a sample generic implementation of a property descriptor doing just that:

```
public class SimplePropertyDescriptor<TComponent, TValue> : PropertyDescriptor
    where TComponent : class
{
    private readonly Func<TComponent, TValue> getValue;
    private readonly Action<TComponent, TValue> setValue;
    private readonly string displayName;
    public SimplePropertyDescriptor(string name, Attribute[] attrs, Func<TComponent, TValue> getValue, Action<TComponent, TValue> setValue = null, string displayName = null)
        : base(name, attrs)
    {
        Debug.Assert(getValue != null);
        this.getValue = getValue;
        this.setValue = setValue;
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }
    public override string DisplayName { get { return displayName ?? base.DisplayName; } }
    public override Type ComponentType { get { return typeof(TComponent); } }
    public override bool IsReadOnly { get { return setValue == null; } }
    public override Type PropertyType { get { return typeof(TValue); } }
    public override bool CanResetValue(object component) { return false; }
    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component) { return false; }
    public override void ResetValue(object component) { }
    public override object GetValue(object component) { return getValue((TComponent)component); }
    public override void SetValue(object component, object value) { setValue((TComponent)component, (TValue)value); }
}
```

sample usage with your stuff:

```
public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
{
    var properties = base.GetProperties(attributes);
    // Custom name property
    properties.Add(new SimplePropertyDescriptor<FeaturePropertyPresentation, string>("FeatureName", attributes,
        getValue: component => component.m_feature.m_name,
        setValue: (component, value) => component.m_feature.m_name = value, // remove this line to make it readonly
        displayName: "Feature Name"
    ));
    return properties;
}
```

and, putting it all together, a small example equivalent to yours:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Samples
{
    // Generic implemenation of a property descriptor
    public class SimplePropertyDescriptor<TComponent, TValue> : PropertyDescriptor
        where TComponent : class
    {
        private readonly Func<TComponent, TValue> getValue;
        private readonly Action<TComponent, TValue> setValue;
        private readonly string displayName;
        public SimplePropertyDescriptor(string name, Attribute[] attrs, Func<TComponent, TValue> getValue, Action<TComponent, TValue> setValue = null, string displayName = null)
            : base(name, attrs)
        {
            Debug.Assert(getValue != null);
            this.getValue = getValue;
            this.setValue = setValue;
            this.displayName = displayName;
        }
        public override string DisplayName { get { return displayName ?? base.DisplayName; } }
        public override Type ComponentType { get { return typeof(TComponent); } }
        public override bool IsReadOnly { get { return setValue == null; } }
        public override Type PropertyType { get { return typeof(TValue); } }
        public override bool CanResetValue(object component) { return false; }
        public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component) { return false; }
        public override void ResetValue(object component) { }
        public override object GetValue(object component) { return getValue((TComponent)component); }
        public override void SetValue(object component, object value) { setValue((TComponent)component, (TValue)value); }
    }
    // Your stuff
    public abstract class PropertyPresentationSubBase : ICustomTypeDescriptor
    {
        public string GetClassName()
        {
            return TypeDescriptor.GetClassName(this, true);
        }

        public AttributeCollection GetAttributes()
        {
            return TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(this, true);
        }

        public String GetComponentName()
        {
            return TypeDescriptor.GetComponentName(this, true);
        }

        public TypeConverter GetConverter()
        {
            return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(this, true);
        }

        public EventDescriptor GetDefaultEvent()
        {
            return TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultEvent(this, true);
        }

        public PropertyDescriptor GetDefaultProperty()
        {
            return TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultProperty(this, true);
        }

        public object GetEditor(Type editorBaseType)
        {
            return TypeDescriptor.GetEditor(this, editorBaseType, true);
        }

        public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents(Attribute[] attributes)
        {
            return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(this, attributes, true);
        }

        public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents()
        {
            return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(this, true);
        }

        public virtual PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
        {
            PropertyDescriptorCollection rtn = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this);

            //rtn = FilterReadonly(rtn, attributes);

            return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(rtn.Cast<PropertyDescriptor>().ToArray());
        }

        public virtual PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
        {

            return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this, true);

        }


        public object GetPropertyOwner(PropertyDescriptor pd)
        {
            return this;
        }

        [Browsable(false)]
        public PropertyPresentationSubBase Parent
        {
            get
            {
                return m_Parent;
            }
            set
            {
                m_Parent = value;
            }
        }

        PropertyPresentationSubBase m_Parent = null;

        [Browsable(false)]
        public Type ValueType
        {
            get
            {
                return valueType;
            }
            set
            {
                valueType = value;
            }
        }

        private Type valueType = null;

        [Browsable(false)]
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return sName;
            }
            set
            {
                sName = value;
            }
        }



        public abstract object GetValue();

        private string sName = string.Empty;

        public abstract void Change(object value);
    }
    public class QuadriFeatureItem
    {
        public QuadriFeatureItem(int featureId, string name)
        {
            m_featureId = featureId;
            m_name = name;

        }
        public int m_featureId;

        public string m_name;
    }
    class FeaturePropertyPresentation : PropertyPresentationSubBase
    {

        public int FeatureId
        {
            get
            {
                return m_feature.m_featureId;

            }
            set { m_feature.m_featureId = value; }
        }

        public FeaturePropertyPresentation(QuadriFeatureItem item)
        {
            m_feature = item;
        }

        private QuadriFeatureItem m_feature;

        public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
        {
            var properties = base.GetProperties(attributes);
            // Custom name property
            properties.Add(new SimplePropertyDescriptor<FeaturePropertyPresentation, string>("FeatureName", attributes,
                getValue: component => component.m_feature.m_name,
                setValue: (component, value) => component.m_feature.m_name = value, // remove this line to make it readonly
                displayName: "Feature Name"
            ));
            return properties;
        }
        public override void Change(object value)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override object GetValue()
        {
            return this;
        }

    }
    // Test
    static class Test
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            var dataSet = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(n => new FeaturePropertyPresentation(new QuadriFeatureItem(n, "Nummer" + n))).ToList();
            var form = new Form();
            var dg = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Parent = form };
            dg.DataSource = dataSet;
            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }
}
```

result:

[image]