# Filling a GridView when datasource is a ITypedList

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, datasource

I am trying to fill a `GridView` with data provided by a `ITypedList`. I have a `Dictionary<string,object>`, and the columns & values are inside. So if the dictionary has:

```
"Name" : "Jack"
"Age" : 20
```

The GridView will have 2 columns, Name and Age, and the values are Jack and 20.

So, the main idea from which I started was the [following SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882214/data-binding-dynamic-data/882246#882246).

The problem I am facing now is how can I fill the GridView based on this list? There also has to be a binding to this elements, so if any of them change, the value in gridview is updated.

I am using this `ITypedList` in another project, with a Janus Grid, and all the magic that I need is done by setting the `DataSource`. The binding also works, so it's not impossible :)

Does anyone have an idea about this?

Thanks!