# Dynamic datagrid's headers and binding

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, datagrid

The problem:

I have a list of objects which have Date, Name, and Value Properties.  Name and Date properties could be different or the same.

```
orange  2012-01-01  1
orange  2013-01-01  0
```

I'd like create a GridView with Headers (which are distinct dates) and rows

```
  Name   2012-01-01   2013-01-01
orange       1            0
```

As you see objects do not have properties like '2012-01-01', so simple binding will not help.

**Question**

How can I create a binding using column's name?

This I'd like to do with XAML or converters, without using UserControl's events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially what you need to do (as you've noticed) is create a list of objects with dynamic properties (that is, properties populated at runtime).  The transformation itself is a pivot on Date, with a sum (?) across value, which you can perform using a GroupBy Linq query in your converter.

Now for the tricky part.  Take a look at this answer:

[Data binding dynamic data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882214/data-binding-dynamic-data)

You need to implement ICustomTypeDescriptor to implement dynamic properties.  Good luck.

Comment: yes, it looks like a pivot transformation, but the purpose is different. I've forgot about datatable and similar things, indeed.

Comment: I've solved my issue using DataTable. Your answer with the that link helps me a lot., thanks

Answer (score 0):

take your list of objects - **create a new list of objects with your conditions**. then simply put the new list as itemssource to a datagrid/itemscontrol.

Comment: I do not know headers at compile time