# PIVOT Table with ViewModel

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am converting the Rows as Columns using PIVOT in SQL Server. Keeping the result set in a `DataTable` and binding the `DataTable` with a `GridView`. As I want to generate the Column Dynamically based on the Rows, I am using PIVOT operation. How do I proceed if i don't want to use `DataTable` and want to use a `ViewModel` in place of DataTable?

Comment: what do you mean by ViewModel ?

Comment: @Waqar, ViewModel is nothing but a view specific Model object. For example you can keep a DataSet or DataTable as a DataSource for a GridView in a View. Here you can replace DataTable or DataSet using Collection of ViewModel.

Comment: sorry freind I'm unable to understand you question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've asked this question before but for winforms. I too had to pivot sql data. The answer was to make use of `System.ComponentModel`.

See top answer here:
[Data binding dynamic data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882214/data-binding-dynamic-data)

Comment: Looks like I am not alone...Thanks..will accept the answer after going through the complete instructions.