# TypeConverter for PropertyDescriptor.Converter

Tags: c#, typeconverter, propertydescriptor

Let's consider the problem described in [Data binding dynamic data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882214/data-binding-dynamic-data). Now have a look at the great solution given by Marc Gravell [Marc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882214/data-binding-dynamic-data/882246#882246). Marc gave the solution without usage of TypeConverter. And now it's time to submit my problem. I'm looking without success for an example of code which combines `TypeConverter` and `PropertyDescriptor.Converter` for a similar problem as this one. Marc provides a simple solution to the string, but what if we add there other types such as i.e. DateTime, int?

P.S. I'm using own implementation of `IBindingList`, `IList`, `ITypedList`, `ICustomTypeDescriptor` for indexer and to wrap  objects on UI... but I'm a rookie when it comes to `TypeConverter`, as well as C# after 10 years of absence in the programming world [necessity, but also a great pleasure].

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I did it like this:

1. I created own `TypeConverter` called `CharacteristicTypeConverter`.
2. In my implementation of PropertyDescriptor's constructor I added:

   `var attrs = new List<Attribute>();

   attrs.Add(new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(CharacteristicTypeConverter)));

   this.AttributeArray = attrs.ToArray();`
3. To pass context to the converter I use Marc Gravell's tip from here: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/676604-expandableobjectconvertors-typeconverters to implement `ITypeDescriptorContext`.
4. In `GetValue/SetValue` of my `PropertyDescriptor` implementation I use the converter as follows: `Converter.ConvertTo(...)`, `Converter.ConvertFrom`