# Where is the documentation for the use of ITypedList by DataGridView?

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

I am facing the need to possibly do some complex data binding to a `DataGridView`. (I will at least need to flatten objects that implement some interface - with the flattening possibly being dictated by how much the implementations actually have in common (but that may not matter here)). I've read that in some cases implementing `ITypedList` may be helpful/necessary:

[Really complex data-binding](http://weblogs.asp.net/fbouma/really-complex-databinding-itypedlist-with-weakly-typed-collections)

[Data binding dynamic data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882214/data-binding-dynamic-data)

But I can't find any documentation for `DataGridView` or `DataGrid` that state that `ITypedList` is used by these controls. For example, there is no mention of it here:

[DataGridView.DataSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx)

Where is the documentation that states that `DataGridView` uses `ITypedList`?

Comment: [How to: Implement the ITypedList Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404298(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I have found good examples on how to implement ITypedList. That is not the question asked here.